# Regex With Colons in Data

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file which I'm looking to remove some data from. The data is separated using a colon ':' as the delimiter. There are approx 9 separations. The data after the 7th column is most often null and thus useless but the additional colons are still there.

An example of the file would like this:

```
column1:column2:column3:column4:column5:column6:column7:column8:column9:column10
```

I hope to remove the info from after column8. So the data to be removed would be:

```
:column9:column10
```

Could someone advise me how to do so in Regex?

I've been reading and no where have I found a way to isolate a colon and text following after x number of colons.

Any help you could offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which tool/language are you using for your regex?

Comment: I am using Perl

Comment: Is that format consistent? Is it `column8` or the 8th instance of `column_:`?

Comment: Consistent formatting

Comment: Maybe `((?:column\d+:){1,8}).*`? Then replace with `\1`.

Comment: Not quite. I want to find and delete the instances after 8.

Comment: Seems to work, `echo "column1:column2:column3:column4:column5:column6:column7:column8:column9:column10" | perl -ne 's/((?:column\d+:){1,8}).*/\1/g; print;'`

Answer (score 4):

```
$_ = join ":", ( split /:/, $_, -1 )[0..7];
```

or

```
s/(?::[^:]*){2}\z//;
```

Comment: Your first suggestion should use the range [0..7] else you will miss column one and include column 9. Your second suggestion removes the last two columns instead of keeping the first eight

Comment: @Ken Schumack, What was I thinking? Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The following regex will keep the first 8 columns and discard all others.

```
s/^[^:]*(?::[^:]*){7}\K.*//;
```

Assumes simple single line records.

Comment: \K (keep ??) -- cool! I have not used that before. I would have used the longer: s/^([^:]*(?::[^:]*){7}).*/$1/;

Comment: @Ken Schumack, Introducing captures slows down the matching.

Comment: @ikegami  yes I know. I was just so happy to find out about the \K modifier. I have never noticed it in any documentation before but I was delighted to "discover" it in this post. Perl certainly is a rich language! BTW: I looked through the output of perldoc perlretut and did not see any mention of \K. Anyone know which perl doc would contain information on it? I'm wondering of course which other modifiers I do not know about :-)

Comment: Found it: perldoc perlre